# Best practice to delete old MetricBeats data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

How do we best delete old data collected via MetricBeats in ElasticSearch periodically? Is there some feature to automatically purge old data or to create new MetricBeats indices after a certain configurable period of time so those old indices can be deleted?
I can see following index being created by metricbeat, it has a date in its name. So, is there a way that it can create new indices after a certain period?

```
health status index                              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   metricbeat-7.6.2-2020.05.06-000001 1   1    4120157            0    836.5mb        836.5mb
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Index LifeCycle Policies looks like best approach to purge old data from Metricbeat indices. You can create or find one in Management Panel in Kibana as shown below:

[image]

I found a default policy was already created for MetricBeat. Edit the policy as per your liking. One can choose max index size for rollover, maximum Age and so on.

[image]
There is a delete phase at the bottom. Enable the same for automatic deletion of old data.

[image]